# How can I set up a function that can be referenced from several event listeners and use different properties for each element? (JS)

Tags: javascript, html

Edit: I found the solution (found at the bottom).

The problem that I am having is that I want to consolidate my code into one small function that can be referenced multiple times. I have a currently working code, which has several functions, one for each event-listener that my webpage has. I am trying to render objects after a user clicks a "button," which is really a div element. Here's some code:

```js
//Constructor Function

function Object(objectType) {
  this.objectType = objectType;
}

//Render function for the objects

Object.prototype.render = function() {
  //Getting the elements, creating them, setting to variables to be used later. 
  let objectDiv = document.createElement('div');
  objectDiv.setAttribute('class', `${this.objectType}Object`);
  objectDiv.textContent = this.objectType;

  let makeButton = document.querySelector(`#${this.objectType}Section`);

  //Appending element to webpage
  makeButton.appendChild(objectDiv);
};

//All the current code above works like it is supposed to. I have a few buttons already that work, but they each have their own function. Like so:

//Setting up Button1 code.
let button1 = document.getElementById("makeObj1");

//Event listener for Button1, which calls the Render function for the Button1 object.
button1.addEventListener("click", goMakeButton1);

function goMakeButton() {
  let button1 = new Object('Obj1');
  button1.render();
}

//And so forth three times, for each button. 

//I want to make it so that there is one section, and I currently have it set up like so:

let button1 = {
  element: document.getElementById('makeObj1'),
  name: 'Obj1',
}
let button2 = {
  element: document.getElementById('makeObj2'),
  name: 'Obj2',
}
let button3 = {
  element: document.getElementById('makeObj3'),
  name: 'Obj3',
}
let button4 = {
  element: document.getElementById('makeObj4'),
  name: 'obj4',
}

catButton.element.addEventListener('click', makeObj);
dogButton.element.addEventListener('click', makeObj);
sheepButton.element.addEventListener('click', makeObj);
horseButton.element.addEventListener('click', makeObj);

function makeObj(object) {
  console.log('I am called');
  //To check my function gets called - it does. 

  let myObject = new Animal(this.name);

  myObject.render();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Animal Farm</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>DOM Manipulation and Events</h1>
  <!-- create one big container -->
  <main id="mainContainer">
    <section id="Obj1Section">
      <div class="make" id="makeButton1">Make Object 1</div>
    </section>

    <section id="Obj2Section">
      <div class="make" id="makeButton2">Make Object 2</div>
    </section>

    <section id="Obj3Section">
      <div class="make" id="makeButton3">Make Object 3</div>
    </section>

    <section id="HorseSection">
      <div class="make" id="makeButton4">Make Objecvt 4</div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
<script src="./script/script.js"></script>

</html>
```

This just gives me the error of not being able to append child of null. When I try to take in a parameter and give each event listener its own parameter to pass, that fails as well and doesn't even allow me to click them. What do I do here?

The fix:

What I did was run an arrow function that called another function, passing a parameter defined in the arrow function, rather than trying to pass a parameter directly to the function from the event listener (it would just run, and then become useless.)

```js
"use strict";
//Creating the constructor function for the buttons
function Button(buttonName) {
  this.buttonName = buttonName;
}

//Render function for Buttons. Able to be used for any button name.
Button.prototype.render = function () {
  //Getting the elements, creating them, setting to variables to be used later. 
  let buttonDiv = document.createElement('div');
  buttonDiv.setAttribute('class',`${this.buttonName}Object`);
  buttonDiv.textContent = this.buttonName;
  
  let makeButton = document.querySelector(`#${this.buttonName}Section`);
  
  //Appending element to webpage
  makeButton.appendChild(buttonDiv);
};

//Setting up the condensed function: 

let buttonOne = document.getElementById('Obj1');
let buttonTwo = document.getElementById('Obj2');
let buttonThree = document.getElementById('Obj3');
let buttonFour = document.getElementById('Obj4');

function buttonMake(button){
  let myButton = new Button (button);

  myButton.render();
}

buttonOne.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  let theButton = 'Obj1';

  makeButton(theButton);
})

buttonTwo.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  let theButton = 'Obj2';

  makeButton(theButton);
})

buttonThree.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  let theButton = 'Obj3';

  makeButton(theButton);
})

buttonFour.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  let theButton = 'Obj4';

  makeButton(theButton);
})
```

Comment: Could you please include your HTML code as well?

Comment: There a so many thing going on here. First: whenever you want to do something with several objects of the same type, use arrays to reference then. Don't make button1...X, make an array `const buttons=[]`
second: Then you can isntall listeners by calling the same function but with different values (use .bind() for that).
third: adding functions to the standard objects prototype can be risky. Better extend these with your own class and add your functions there.